# next/prev button issue in iPad movie player contoll style 3

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayer

I am developing an iPad app which has plays videos from URLs.

I am using control style 3, but there is a strange problem while I press done button. It gets video finish notification but when I press next or previous button it doesn't get finish notification.

Answer (score 0):

ok i have solved ...
i m playing movie by this way
[movieplayerviewcontrollerobject.movieplayer play];
that's y i m not getting didfinish notification while press on next button.

now i m using [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:movieplayerviewcontrollerobject];

and i m getting notification.